# Same column with multiple index names. It is possible. What is the use?

Tags: sql-server-2005, indexing

For me there is no need/intention to create multiple index names for a same column. When i'm studying about index i tried the following test.  What is the use of the same? Is there any feature?

What i have tried is:

```
create index id on TestIndex(EmployeeMumber)
create index id1 on TestIndex(EmployeeMumber)
create index id2 on TestIndex(EmployeeMumber)
```

The result is: Command(s) completed successfully.

Thanks

Comment: Different index names for same columns are not necessary. Only one enough. It just make data storage more and DB engine needs to update all indexes once data update in table. It mean, waste of Server resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't prevent you from creating duplicate indexes (though [there has been an unsuccessful push to change this](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/313227/sql-server-allows-to-created-duplicate-indexes)). The "won't fix" is probably largely for backward compatibility reasons - there were probably use cases in previous versions where people would create a new index before dropping an old one, back when options like `DROP_EXISTING` or rebuilding online didn't exist. As new features in the engine evolve, such as `INCLUDE` columns, filtered indexes, etc. it is also more complex to determine whether or not two indexes are, in fact, duplicates.