# Is there any specific use of multiple index with different index name on a single column of a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have table in my database which looks like this (names changed to comply with NDA)

```
CREATE TABLE `Job` (
  `id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `JobTypeFK_idx` (`type`),
  KEY `JobStatusFK_idx` (`status`),
  KEY `JobTypeFK_idx1` (`type`),
  KEY `JobStatusFK_idx1` (`status`),
  KEY `JobParentIDFK_idx` (`parent_id`),
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have read the significance of naming Indexes as per this question

- [significance of index name in creating an index (mySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601138/significance-of-index-name-in-creating-an-index-mysql)

unfortunately it doesn't talk about the situation where there is more than one duplicate index on the same column.

There is another question, but relevant to SQL Server

- [Same column with multiple index names. It is possible. What is the use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205850/same-column-with-multiple-index-names-it-is-possible-what-is-the-use)

Unfortunately I am not working with SQL-Server. I was cleaning up the schema to use newer MySQL features when I came across duplicate index names, which I want to remove. I just wanted to know if there is any possible problems which I might face later? If I keep worrying about breaking something, then I would never be able to clean up the schema.

Comment: The only thing multiple indexes with the same columns will do is waste disk space on the server.

Comment: They not only waste disk space, they also slow down inserts and updates. Just get rid of those duplicate indexes (some DBMS wouldn't even allow this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the only place where index names are used (other than DDL statements to modify and drop indexes) is in [*index hints*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-hints.html). This allows you to suggest or force MySQL to use a specific index in a query, and it identifies them by name. If you ever make use of this feature, and you remove the index that's required by the query, the query will get an error.

As this feature is very rarely used, you can probably remove the redundant indexes without worrying about breaking anything. On the off chance that you do use this feature, just make sure you remove the index that isn't named. On the really unlikely chance that you have different queries that force different names of indexes on the same column, rewrite them to use the same index name, and then remove the other index.

You can search your code for the regular expression:

```
\b(using|ignore|force)\s+(index|key)\b
```

to find any uses of this feature.